# Is there support for 3D convolution kernels with complex variables in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a 3D CVNN in tensorflow on the GPU, but most of my variables are complex64. All worked when all of my variables were float32.

I've sorted through a few related issues, but I'm stuck on this error:

```
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel 
was registered to support Op 'Conv3D' with these attrs.  Registered kernels:
          device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
          device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
          device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]

    [[Node: Conv3D = Conv3D[T=DT_COMPLEX64, padding="SAME", 
    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]](Reshape, Complex)]]
```

Does tensorflow have complex support for 3D convnets yet? Or is it likely a bug in my own implementation?

Answer (score 0):

No, Tensorflow doesn't support complex 3D convolutions yet. I suggest you open a feature request on Tensorflow's github issues page.

Even better, implement complex 3D convolution support and send a pull request :-)